# Rails jquery include blank in selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

When a user is creating a new workorder, they first choose the workgroup, then they can select the Assigned To person from a dropdown containing a list of employees in that workgroup.  Do do that, I'm using jquery to create the picklist of employees in that group.

But, I don't know how to add a blank selection via the jquery.

This is the view code:

```
            <%= f.grouped_collection_select :employee_id, Workgroup.order(:id), :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, :include_blank => true %>
```

This is the jquery cofeescript:

```
employees = $('#workorder_employee_id').html()
$('#workorder_workgroup_id').change ->
  group = $('#workorder_workgroup_id :selected').text()
  options = $(employees).filter("optgroup[label='#{group}']").html()
  if options
    $('#workorder_employee_id').html(options)
    $('#workorder_employee_id').parent().show()
  else
    $('#workorder_employee_id').empty()
    $('#workorder_employee_id').parent().hide()
```

How can I add a blank in the picklist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the first line after the `if` statement to

```
$('#workorder_employee_id').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>' + options)
```